# Why I dont see a MessageBox? c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have just created a program with that code:

```
class INF2 : Form1
{
    public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Zaznacz();

    }
    private void Zaznacz()
    {

        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Dot Net Perls is awesome.");
        }

    }
}
```

where the function inherits from:

```
    public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

inside the `Form1` ( it's a normal checkBox) and I want to see a messagebox when I press the checkbox by the `INF2` class (necessarily inheritance)

Comment: You might have to use `override`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your compiler warnings.

You created a new method that happens to have the same name as the base method, but doesn't actually have anything to do with it.

You need to use `virtual` and `override`.

Comment: like this ?     class INF2 : Form1
    {

        public override void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zaznacz();